# Jdbc sql syntax error for date

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

```
ResultSet resultObj = statementObj.executeQuery("SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY WHERE START_DATE > Convert(datetime, '2001-01-13' )");
```

I get this error while Iam executing the program:

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "DATETIME": invalid identifier

Comment: It always helps to read the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Oracle, use Oracle syntax:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM JOB_HISTORY
WHERE START_DATE > DATE '2001-01-13';
```

The `date` keyword allows you to use ISO-standard syntax for date constants.

Comment: It would be more flexible to use a prepared statement and not worry about what format the DB actually wants. Leave the detail work to the JDBC driver, thats its job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ResultSet resultObj = statementObj.executeQuery("SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY WHERE START_DATE > '2001-01-13'");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Query ="SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID FROM JOB_HISTORY WHERE START_DATE >'2001-01-13' ";
ResultSet resultObj = statementObj.executeQuery(Query);
```